# Ajax how do I clear this.responseText streams?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this function. When I call some php pages that have lengthy execution that is streaming information I want to remove old information.

I have tried `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";` but it appears that `this.responseText` is holding onto the entire bulk of data and just replaces all the erased text.

```
function phppush(Page, Send){
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " <img src=\" images/loading.gif \"\> ";
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((this.readyState == 4 || this.readyState == 3) && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText;    
    }
}
xhttp.open("POST", Page, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send(Send);
}
```

Is there a way to reset or clear `this.responseText`?

Comment: try get "output" element to var and refer to null;

Comment: where to you want to set content of `output` empty ?

Comment: `this.responseText = "";`

Comment: @Ben Kolya Mansley tried that.